# Prove $a|b \wedge b|a \implies a=\pm b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}$. Show that

$a\mid b$, $b\mid a$ $\implies a=\pm b$.

I can see why this is true, but not write it down.

Comment: Hint: $a\mid b$ implies that $b=c_1a$ for some integer $c_1$. Similarly you get $a=c_2b$. what can you deduce from $c_1c_2=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a|b, b=an$ where $n$ is an integer

Similarly, $b|a\implies a=bm$ where $m$ is an integer

$\implies ab=abmn\iff mn=1$

But $m,n$ are integers, so what are the possible values of $m,n?$

Answer (score 1):

$a=tb$ and $b=sa$ gives $a=tsa$, which means $ts=1$. Now, $t$ and $s$ are both integers, so...

Answer (score 0):

If $a|b$ then $|a|\leq |b|$. Similarly $b|a$ implies $|b|\leq |a|$. So $a=b$ or $a=-b$.